# Using Cloud Recognition Vuforia and Unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I have a problem with vuforia unity 3d! After adding CloudRecognition to Unity view then how can we add CloudRecoTarget to view?
As i have seen in this "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9tksyhVlIMQ" the video, they have a CloudRecoTarget for adding Models to work. But how can we add it?

[image: sample unity view]

Answer (score 0):

You need to add cloud reco targets on Vuforia cloud server. Based on the access and secter key, the application will identify your cloud server and can detect images uploaded there. 
at
Now, once you have multiple targets loaded, when any particlar target is detected by application, we get the name of the target to identify which target is detected.

Hope this helps. If you need further clarification, will be happt to help

Comment: I found it , actually the Cloud Reco target is sth like ImageTarget, CylinderTarget etc. thanks for your answer ,anyways.